# Dealing with SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE and TLS1_ALERT_NO_RENEGOTIATION in SChannel

Tags: ssl, schannel

I'm working with SChannel at the moment for an async (IOCP) based server and I've got most things working fine but I'm having a problem with renegotiation. Specifically, when peer A sends peer B a request to renegotiate and peer B responds with an TLS1 `NO RENEGOTIATION` alert how does peer A continue? I seem to have an invalid context at the point where I get the `SEC_I_NO_RENEGOTIATION` response and this prevents me from being able to continue to use the stream...

**Updated** I've done some more testing and it doesn't seem to be an invalid context but I do get `SEC_E_ENCRYPT_FAILURE` from the next call to Encrypt...

Is a request to renegotiate actually denyable? Or is `NO RENEGOTIATION` alert simply an informative error message which now means that the connection is useless? If so, why is it commented as being a 'warning' rather than an 'error'?? Nope; the TLS RFC (5246) clearly states that its up to the peer to decide if we can continue after a no renegotiation alert...

**Updated** It doesn't make any difference if I send the TLS alert using `ApplyControlToken() or if I send it using EncryptMessage() with SECQOP_WRAP_OOB_DATA`...

Comment: (for posterity.)  It seems people on the Chromium team [have the same problem](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36835) and they link to this issue.

Comment: I'd rather they'd found a solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

There was a HOTFIX issued for this a while back for Intel AMT based hardware. Essentially, the root certificate was stored as an SHA-1 hash instead of caching the entire certificate. SSPI passes all certificates EXCEPT the root, expecting the root to have this certificate for trust-chain verification. When the full root didn't exist, SSPI was forcing a re-negotiate.

The hotfix updates schannel on Win 2003 systems with Intel AMT installed.

Check out this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942841

Comment: Yet the situation I describe is on both Vista and Windows 7 and doesn't in any way include Intel AMT stuff ... 

I fail to see how this is relevant, but then perhaps I just don't understand?

Comment: No, you failed to mention that. You're right it isn't relevant for your situation. Perhaps, it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you: [Code Project: SSLSocket](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sslsocket.aspx).

Comment: Looks like it's just a simple wrapper around the platform sdk example code. :(